# как правильнее реализовать Fragments

Tags: android, listview, android-fragment, gridview

есть такой код, переключение list/grid осуществляется через меню, хочу сделать чтоб не просто было visible/unvisible, а через фрагменты. подскажите, как правильнее реализовать? пробовал вот тут поставить условие типа : if true то грузим Activity1, иначе Activity2, которые в свою очередь грузили свои фрагменты, но не то.. так как приходится дублировать весь код из mainActivity, если во фрагментах оставить только адаптер и заполнение, то опять же мне сначала надо в MainActivity setContentView что-то прописать..запутался совсем.. какие идеи?

```
    @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.item) {
        boolean isChecked = !item.isChecked();
        item.setChecked(isChecked);
        item.setTitle(isChecked ? "Show GridView" : "Show ListView");
        showListView(isChecked);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

общий код

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static ArrayList<Model_Melodies.Melodies> melodiesList;
private Model_Melodies melodies;
private ListView mListView;
private GridView mGridView;
protected static boolean mIsListVisible;
private SharedPreferences mSettings;
protected static AdapterListMelodies adapter;
public final int LIMIT = 20;
public final String BASE_URL = "https://api-content-beeline.intech-global.com";
public int countItems = 0;
public String JSON_URL = BASE_URL +
        "/public/marketplaces/1/tags/4/melodies/?limit=%d&from=%d";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity_fragment);

    mSettings = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);

    melodies = new Model_Melodies();
    melodies.setMelodies(melodiesList);
    melodiesList = new ArrayList<>();
    adapter = new AdapterListMelodies(MainActivity.this, melodiesList);

    mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    if (mListView != null) {
        mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    mGridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridLayout);
    if (mGridView != null) {
        mGridView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    customLoadMoreDataFromApi(countItems);

    mListView.setOnScrollListener(new EndlessScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLoadMore(int page, int totalItemsCount) {
            customLoadMoreDataFromApi(page);
            return true;
        }
    });

  mGridView.setOnScrollListener(new EndlessScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLoadMore(int page, int totalItemsCount) {
            customLoadMoreDataFromApi(page);
            return true;
        }
    });
}

private void customLoadMoreDataFromApi(int page) {
    countItems = LIMIT * page;
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(
            Request.Method.GET,
            String.format(JSON_URL, LIMIT, countItems),
            null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

            try {
                toList(response);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        }
    });
    queue.add(jsObjRequest);
}

public ArrayList toList(JSONObject response) throws JSONException {
    JSONArray values = response.getJSONArray("melodies");
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject o = (JSONObject) values.get(i);
        melodiesList.add(new Model_Melodies.Melodies(
                o.getString("picUrl"), o.getString("title"), o.getString("artist"), o.getString("demoUrl")));
    }
    return melodiesList;
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    menu.findItem(R.id.item).setChecked(mIsListVisible);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.item) {
        boolean isChecked = !item.isChecked();
        item.setChecked(isChecked);
        item.setTitle(isChecked ? "Show GridView" : "Show ListView");
        showListView(isChecked);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

private void showListView(boolean show) {
    mIsListVisible = show;
    mListView.setVisibility(show ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
    mGridView.setVisibility(show ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    showListView(mSettings.getBoolean("show_list", true));
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mSettings.edit().putBoolean("show_list", mIsListVisible).apply();
}
```

}
UPDATE:
 исправил адаптер унаследованный от Baseadapter, но все равно не так, что -то..

```
public class AdapterListMelodies extends
    RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterListMelodies.ViewHolder> {

private Context mContext;
private ArrayList<Model_Melodies.Melodies> items;
private DisplayImageOptions options;
private Model_Melodies.Melodies modelMelodiesMelodies;
protected ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();

public AdapterListMelodies(Context context, ArrayList<Model_Melodies.Melodies> items) {
    mContext = context;
    this.items = items;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    modelMelodiesMelodies = items.get(position);
    holder.nameArtist.setText(modelMelodiesMelodies.getArtist());
    final Model_Melodies.Melodies modelMelodiesMelodiesCopy = modelMelodiesMelodies;
    holder.nameArtist.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (v.getId() == R.id.nameArtist) {
                Intent i = new Intent(mContext, Activity_Player.class);
                String imgUri = modelMelodiesMelodiesCopy.getPicUrl();
                String soundUri = modelMelodiesMelodiesCopy.getDemoUrl();
                i.putExtra(Activity_Player.EXTRA_IMAGE_URL, imgUri);
                i.putExtra(Activity_Player.EXTRA_SOUND_URL, soundUri);
                mContext.startActivity(i);
            }
        }
    });
    holder.nameSounds.setText(modelMelodiesMelodies.getTitle());
    imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
    imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(mContext));
    options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.ic_stub)
            .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.ic_empty)
            .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.ic_error)
            .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.IN_SAMPLE_INT)
            .cacheInMemory(true)
            .cacheOnDisk(true)
            .build();
    imageLoader.displayImage(modelMelodiesMelodies.getPicUrl(), holder.cover, options);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return items.size();
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.listitems, parent, false);
    ViewHolder pvh = new ViewHolder(v);
    return pvh;
}

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public ImageView cover;
    public TextView nameArtist;
    public TextView nameSounds;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        nameArtist = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.nameArtist);
        nameSounds = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.nameSounds);
        cover = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    }
}
```

}
 UPDATE2:

public class ListFragment extends Fragment {
    private static View view;
    private ListView mListView;

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_customview,container,false);

    mListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    if (mListView != null) {
        mListView.setAdapter(MainActivity.adapter);
    }
    MainActivity.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    return  view;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вместо использования устаревшего `ListView` и `GridView` используйте `RecyclerView` и меняйте в нём лишь `LayoutManager`.
Так вы сможете и списком отображать и сеткой всего лишь поменяв `LayoutManager` у `RecyclerView`

Comment: сейчас посмотрел код, получается надо сделать 2 viewHolder для list grid, также 2 адаптера.так ли?

Comment: @Сергей, можно ограничиться и один адаптером и одним холдером, если элементы одинаковые в обих случаях (сетка и список)

Comment: можете сказать правильно ли? а как сделать чтоб и gridiew тоже показывало?

Comment: Ну теперь вы можете как-то так менять: `recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(numOfColsInGridLayoutManager, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL));` и `recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(ctx));` После чего вызвать `recyclerView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: что-то не то я делаю совсем... по идее должен был поменять только методы в adapter, а получается, что весь код переписал уже..

Comment: @Сергей, адаптер может быть один для обоих случаев. А вот в момент когда вам надо поменять сетку на список надо переназначить мэнеджер.

Comment: можете подсказать? если делать через обычный list/grid view то как реализовать лучше? у меня есть код mainActivity выше кож, там вся обработка идет, и я создал фрагмент listFragment  в нем просто установил адаптер и обновление его, тоже самое думаю сделать для grid , но проблема в том что я загружаю совсем другой layout, как правильнее реализовать? Recycler view не подходит